# Sort based on values under each hierarchy alphabetically

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, treeview

I have an SQL table with the following structure and values

```
AccountID   | Company  |  ValuePath  | ParentID
--------------------------------------------------
    1          ZA           0/1           0
    2          SS           1/2           1
    3          BB           1/3           1
    4          JJ           1/3/4         3
    5          AB           1/3/5         3
    6          ST           1/3/6         3
    7          KK           1/7           1
    8          ZZ           1/3/4/8       4
    9          AA           1/3/4/9       4
    10         CC           1/3/4/10      4
    11         AA           0/1           0
------------------------------------------------------
```

The valuepath am using in a treeview in asp.net. As you can see there is a parent child relation exists in the same table. but the problem am facing is the sorting under each tree view nodes. When I bind this there is apparently no sorting on the treeview. But I need to sort this table perfectly alphabetically before binding.

So the resulting tablet should be like this

```
AccountID   | Company  |  ValuePath  | ParentID
--------------------------------------------------
    11         AA           0/1           0
    1          ZA           0/1           0
    3          BB           1/3           1
    5          AB           1/3/5         3
    4          JJ           1/3/4         3
    9          AA           1/3/4/9       4
    10         CC           1/3/4/10      4
    8          ZZ           1/3/4/8       4
    6          ST           1/3/6         3
    7          KK           1/7           1
    2          SS           1/2           1

------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope the result table is clear. That means each nodes from parent to child will be alphabetically sorted. Also after each node if there is any child nodes under it will be listed before listing that nodes sibling. And the child nodes also will be sorted alphabetically.
**Updates**
As an example the accountIDs 8 & 10 and 9 also under the parentAccount 4. So when taking these three which is under the account 4 and sorting them based on the companyname alphabetically, the order will be as in the result table which is AA,CC,ZZ Hope you got it

Comment: Both the accountIDs 8 & 10 and 9 also under the parentAccount 4. So when taking these three which is under the account 4 and sorting them based on the companyname alphabetically, the order will be as in the result table which is AA,CC,ZZ
Hope you got it.

Comment: probably more appropriate to add your comment to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CTE which works while assuming that there is one seed node.
It should work in your case with two seed nodes where one is without any child nodes.

```
WITH CTEEX(Company, Accountid, ValuePath  ,parentid, Sort)
AS (SELECT Company,Accountid,ValuePath  , parentid,Company as Sort FROM Table_1 
    WHERE parentId =0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  a.Company,a.Accountid,a.ValuePath  ,a.parentid,CONVERT (nvarchar(2000), RTRIM(Sort ) + '|    '+ a.Company)
    FROM Table_1 a JOIN CTEEX b on a.parentId=b.Accountid
 )
SELECT Accountid,Company,  ValuePath  ,parentid
FROM CTEEX 
ORDER BY Sort
```

Comment: Its triggering an error
"Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Sort" of recursive query "CTEEX"."
Sorry am not an SQL expert. So requesting your support

Comment: SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO

  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
   [Valuepath] [nchar](10) NULL,
   [Accountid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Company] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
   [parentId] [int] NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
   [Accountid] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

  GO

Comment: This query is great... But unfortunately it only returns if I pass the  first accountID (That means those having parentid is 0). If I pass any child accountid, it returns blank.. Would you please help me for that..

Comment: Please elaborate on -" If I pass any child accountid, it returns blank"

Comment: OK.. Boss I made that work. I declared a ParentID variable and collected the ParentID of the AccountID I pass to the query.  That ParentID used instaed of parentid=0
Thanks for that nice query.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.